# Intel xrandr resolutions are not displayed in the standard format with modelines

Tags: linux, x11, xorg, xrandr, intel

I am using a Intel graphic card and added modelines to the `xorg` config. This is my `xorg.conf`:

```
# /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/01-intel.conf
Section "Device"
 
  Identifier "intel(0)"
  Driver "intel"

  Option "TearFree" "true"
  Option "DRI" "2"
  Option "ReprobeOutputs" "true"
  Option "HotPlug" "false"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier  "Screen1"
        Device          "intel(0)"
        Monitor         "DP1"
        SubSection "Display"
                 Modes           "1280x1024_60.00" "1440x900_60.00" "1600x1200_60.00" "1920x1080_60.00" "1280x1024_75.00" "1280x1024_85.00" "1920x1080_120.00" "1920x1200_60.00" "2560x1440_60.00" "3840x2160_60.00" "1440x900_120.00" "1280x1024_120.00" "1600x1200_120.00" "1920x1200_120.00" "2560x1440_120.00" "3840x2160_120.00" "1440x900_144.00" "1280x1024_144.00" "1600x1200_144.00" "1920x1080_144.00" "1920x1200_144.00" "2560x1440_144.00" "3840x2160_144.00" "1440x900_240.00" "1280x1024_240.00" "1600x1200_240.00" "1920x1080_240.00" "1920x1200_240.00" "2560x1440_240.00" "3840x2160_240.00" 
        EndSubSection
EndSection



Section "Screen"
        Identifier  "Screen2"
        Device          "intel(0)"
        Monitor         "DP2"
        SubSection "Display"
                 Modes           "1280x1024_60.00" "1440x900_60.00" "1600x1200_60.00" "1920x1080_60.00" "1280x1024_75.00" "1280x1024_85.00" "1920x1080_120.00" "1920x1200_60.00" "2560x1440_60.00" "3840x2160_60.00" "1440x900_120.00" "1280x1024_120.00" "1600x1200_120.00" "1920x1200_120.00" "2560x1440_120.00" "3840x2160_120.00" "1440x900_144.00" "1280x1024_144.00" "1600x1200_144.00" "1920x1080_144.00" "1920x1200_144.00" "2560x1440_144.00" "3840x2160_144.00" "1440x900_240.00" "1280x1024_240.00" "1600x1200_240.00" "1920x1080_240.00" "1920x1200_240.00" "2560x1440_240.00" "3840x2160_240.00" 
        EndSubSection
EndSection



Section "Monitor"
        Identifier  "DP1"
        Option          "Primary"       "true"
        Option          "DPMS""
        Option          "ModeValidation" "AllowNonEdidModes, NoDFPNativeResolutionCheck,NoVirtualSizeCheck,NoMaxPClkCheck,NoHorizSyncCheck,NoVertRefreshCheck,NoWidthAlignmentCheck"
        #Modeline        "1600x1200_60.00"  161.00  1600 1712 1880 2160  1200 1203 1207 1245 -hsync +vsync
        Modeline "1280x1024_60.00"  109.00  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync
        Modeline "1440x900_60.00"  106.50  1440 1528 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync
        Modeline "1600x1200_60.00"  161.00  1600 1712 1880 2160  1200 1203 1207 1245 -hsync +vsync
        Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
        Modeline "1280x1024_75.00"  138.75  1280 1368 1504 1728  1024 1027 1034 1072 -hsync +vsync
        Modeline "1280x1024_85.00"  159.50  1280 1376 1512 1744  1024 1027 1034 1078 -hsync +vsync
        Modeline "1920x1080_120.00"  369.50  1920 2080 2288 2656  1080 1083 1088 1160 -hsync +vsync
        Modeline "1920x1200_60.00"  193.25  1920 2056 2256 2592  1200 1203 1209 1245 -hsync +vsync
        Modeline "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
        Modeline "3840x2160_60.00"  712.75  3840 4160 4576 5312  2160 2163 2168 2237 -hsync +vsync
        Modeline "1440x900_120.00"  228.25  1440 1552 1704 1968  900 903 909 967 -hsync +vsync
        Modeline "1280x1024_120.00"  232.00  1280 1384 1520 1760  1024 1027 1034 1100 -hsync +vsync
        Modeline "1600x1200_120.00"  343.50  1600 1736 1912 2224  1200 1203 1207 1289 -hsync +vsync
        Modeline "1920x1200_120.00"  410.50  1920 2080 2288 2656  1200 1203 1209 1289 -hsync +vsync
        Modeline "2560x1440_120.00"  661.25  2560 2784 3064 3568  1440 1443 1448 1545 -hsync +vsync
        Modeline "3840x2160_120.00"  1498.25  3840 4192 4616 5392  2160 2163 2168 2316 -hsync +vsync
        Modeline "1440x900_144.00"  280.00  1440 1560 1712 1984  900 903 909 981 -hsync +vsync
        Modeline "1280x1024_144.00"  285.00  1280 1392 1528 1776  1024 1027 1034 1116 -hsync +vsync
        Modeline "1600x1200_144.00"  418.25  1600 1736 1912 2224  1200 1203 1207 1307 -hsync +vsync
        Modeline "1920x1080_144.00"  452.50  1920 2088 2296 2672  1080 1083 1088 1177 -hsync +vsync
        Modeline "1920x1200_144.00"  502.50  1920 2088 2296 2672  1200 1203 1209 1307 -hsync +vsync
        Modeline "2560x1440_144.00"  808.75  2560 2792 3072 3584  1440 1443 1448 1568 -hsync +vsync
        Modeline "3840x2160_144.00"  1829.25  3840 4200 4624 5408  2160 2163 2168 2350 -hsync +vsync
        Modeline "1440x900_240.00"  503.25  1440 1568 1728 2016  900 903 909 1041 -hsync +vsync
        Modeline "1280x1024_240.00"  508.75  1280 1400 1536 1792  1024 1027 1034 1184 -hsync +vsync
        Modeline "1600x1200_240.00"  750.25  1600 1752 1928 2256  1200 1203 1207 1386 -hsync +vsync
        Modeline "1920x1080_240.00"  809.50  1920 2104 2312 2704  1080 1083 1088 1248 -hsync +vsync
        Modeline "1920x1200_240.00"  899.25  1920 2104 2312 2704  1200 1203 1209 1386 -hsync +vsync
        Modeline "2560x1440_240.00"  1442.50  2560 2800 3088 3616  1440 1443 1448 1663 -hsync +vsync
        Modeline "3840x2160_240.00"  3253.25  3840 4208 4640 5440  2160 2163 2168 2492 -hsync +vsync
EndSection


Section "Monitor"
       Identifier   "DP2"
       Option      "LeftOf"        "DP1"
       Option          "DPMS"
       Option          "ModeValidation" "AllowNonEdidModes, NoDFPNativeResolutionCheck,NoVirtualSizeCheck,NoMaxPClkCheck,NoHorizSyncCheck,NoVertRefreshCheck,NoWidthAlignmentCheck"
       #Modeline        "1600x1200_60.00"  161.00  1600 1712 1880 2160  1200 1203 1207 1245 -hsync +vsync
       Modeline "1280x1024_60.00"  109.00  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync
       Modeline "1440x900_60.00"  106.50  1440 1528 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync
       Modeline "1600x1200_60.00"  161.00  1600 1712 1880 2160  1200 1203 1207 1245 -hsync +vsync
       Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
       Modeline "1280x1024_75.00"  138.75  1280 1368 1504 1728  1024 1027 1034 1072 -hsync +vsync
       Modeline "1280x1024_85.00"  159.50  1280 1376 1512 1744  1024 1027 1034 1078 -hsync +vsync
       Modeline "1920x1080_120.00"  369.50  1920 2080 2288 2656  1080 1083 1088 1160 -hsync +vsync
       Modeline "1920x1200_60.00"  193.25  1920 2056 2256 2592  1200 1203 1209 1245 -hsync +vsync
       Modeline "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
       Modeline "3840x2160_60.00"  712.75  3840 4160 4576 5312  2160 2163 2168 2237 -hsync +vsync
       Modeline "1440x900_120.00"  228.25  1440 1552 1704 1968  900 903 909 967 -hsync +vsync
       Modeline "1280x1024_120.00"  232.00  1280 1384 1520 1760  1024 1027 1034 1100 -hsync +vsync
       Modeline "1600x1200_120.00"  343.50  1600 1736 1912 2224  1200 1203 1207 1289 -hsync +vsync
       Modeline "1920x1200_120.00"  410.50  1920 2080 2288 2656  1200 1203 1209 1289 -hsync +vsync
       Modeline "2560x1440_120.00"  661.25  2560 2784 3064 3568  1440 1443 1448 1545 -hsync +vsync
       Modeline "3840x2160_120.00"  1498.25  3840 4192 4616 5392  2160 2163 2168 2316 -hsync +vsync
       Modeline "1440x900_144.00"  280.00  1440 1560 1712 1984  900 903 909 981 -hsync +vsync
       Modeline "1280x1024_144.00"  285.00  1280 1392 1528 1776  1024 1027 1034 1116 -hsync +vsync
       Modeline "1600x1200_144.00"  418.25  1600 1736 1912 2224  1200 1203 1207 1307 -hsync +vsync
       Modeline "1920x1080_144.00"  452.50  1920 2088 2296 2672  1080 1083 1088 1177 -hsync +vsync
       Modeline "1920x1200_144.00"  502.50  1920 2088 2296 2672  1200 1203 1209 1307 -hsync +vsync
       Modeline "2560x1440_144.00"  808.75  2560 2792 3072 3584  1440 1443 1448 1568 -hsync +vsync
       Modeline "3840x2160_144.00"  1829.25  3840 4200 4624 5408  2160 2163 2168 2350 -hsync +vsync
       Modeline "1440x900_240.00"  503.25  1440 1568 1728 2016  900 903 909 1041 -hsync +vsync
       Modeline "1280x1024_240.00"  508.75  1280 1400 1536 1792  1024 1027 1034 1184 -hsync +vsync
       Modeline "1600x1200_240.00"  750.25  1600 1752 1928 2256  1200 1203 1207 1386 -hsync +vsync
       Modeline "1920x1080_240.00"  809.50  1920 2104 2312 2704  1080 1083 1088 1248 -hsync +vsync
       Modeline "1920x1200_240.00"  899.25  1920 2104 2312 2704  1200 1203 1209 1386 -hsync +vsync
       Modeline "2560x1440_240.00"  1442.50  2560 2800 3088 3616  1440 1443 1448 1663 -hsync +vsync
       Modeline "3840x2160_240.00"  3253.25  3840 4208 4640 5440  2160 2163 2168 2492 -hsync +vsync
EndSection
```

`xrandr` gives me some resolution in the normal format and some resolutions in the format I defined in modelines.

Is there a way to configure it to show always the standard format?

This is standard format:

```
   1024x768      60.00
```

and this is the custom modeline format:

```
  3840x2160_240.00 239.98
```

I need it because I have scripts to adjust the resolution and for that I wanted a normalized format.
This is what `xrandr` gives me back:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3200 x 1200, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP1 connected primary 1600x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1280x1024_60.00  59.89 +
   3840x2160_240.00 239.98  
   3840x2160_144.00 143.94  
   3840x2160_120.00 119.98  
   3840x2160_60.00  59.98  
   2560x1440_240.00 239.88  
   2560x1440_144.00 143.91  
   2560x1440_120.00 119.95  
   2560x1440_60.00  59.96  
   1920x1200_240.00 239.94  
   1920x1200_144.00 143.89  
   1920x1200_120.00 119.90  
   1920x1200_60.00  59.88  
   1920x1080_240.00 239.88  
   1920x1080_144.00 143.88  
   1920x1080_120.00 119.93  
   1920x1080_60.00  59.96  
   1600x1200_240.00 239.94  
   1600x1200_144.00 143.89  
   1600x1200_120.00 119.82  
   1600x1200_60.00  59.87* 
   1280x1024_240.00 239.78  
   1280x1024_144.00 143.79  
   1280x1024_120.00 119.83  
   1280x1024_85.00  84.84  
   1280x1024_75.00  74.90  
   1440x900_240.00 239.80  
   1440x900_144.00 143.86  
   1440x900_120.00 119.94  
   1440x900_60.00  59.89  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
DP2 connected 1600x1200+1600+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1280x1024_60.00  59.89 +
   3840x2160_240.00 239.98  
   3840x2160_144.00 143.94  
   3840x2160_120.00 119.98  
   3840x2160_60.00  59.98  
   2560x1440_240.00 239.88  
   2560x1440_144.00 143.91  
   2560x1440_120.00 119.95  
   2560x1440_60.00  59.96  
   1920x1200_240.00 239.94  
   1920x1200_144.00 143.89  
   1920x1200_120.00 119.90  
   1920x1200_60.00  59.88  
   1920x1080_240.00 239.88  
   1920x1080_144.00 143.88  
   1920x1080_120.00 119.93  
   1920x1080_60.00  59.96  
   1600x1200_240.00 239.94  
   1600x1200_144.00 143.89  
   1600x1200_120.00 119.82  
   1600x1200_60.00  59.87* 
   1280x1024_240.00 239.78  
   1280x1024_144.00 143.79  
   1280x1024_120.00 119.83  
   1280x1024_85.00  84.84  
   1280x1024_75.00  74.90  
   1440x900_240.00 239.80  
   1440x900_144.00 143.86  
   1440x900_120.00 119.94  
   1440x900_60.00  59.89  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```